# Test subscription in Xamarin.Android are always in Payment Pending state

Tags: xamarin.android, in-app-subscription

I've setup a monthly subscription with a 1-month free trial and I've also set my Play Store email as a tester.

When I purchase a subscription, the Android "popup" correctly says that it's a test and that I have a 1-month free trial, so, I keep the "Test card always approve" setting and accept.

Now, the purchase info returned by Montemagno's InAppPurchase plugin (and I've also checked this directly by calling the IInAppBillinService API myself) returns the subscription with a PaymentPending status (a code 0 in the IInAppBillinService return json).

I've also tried a test subscription WITHOUT free trial, which gives the same response.

After every test renew iteration, calling GetPurchases verifies the subscription still says PaymentPending.

I'm at a loss.

How can I verify the subscription is within the free trial period? Does the status ever change to Purchased (1 in the return json) and jow can I test that?

Comment: Hi Rafael, I'm facing the exact same issue at the moment! Looks like there are two bugs filed on the Montemango plugin related to the issue.. One is closed https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/124 and one is open https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/165. Seems like it was closed without any 'fix'. I think you have to assume if GetPurchases returns a purchase that it is active. I'll report back if I find more.

Comment: Jeremy, the underlying Google API IInAppBillingService also returns PaymentPending, so it's not really a bug in Montemagno's plugin.

GetPurchases only returns active subs, that much is a fact. The problem is how to verify the subscription's state and it seems only to be possible with the Developer API.

Comment: From what I can find using the Developer API seems to be the only way... The Montemagno plugin attempts to parse "paymentState" from the RESPONSE_IAP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST.. however according to table 7 (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference) there is no such property in the INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA structure. Therefore it seems there is no way to check the payment state with the result of GetPurchase.

Comment: I guess I'll rely on the AutoRenewable boolean property. As long as it's value is true, the subscription is active within the grace period or on hold, so the user should still have access to the subscription content.
That should be enough.

Comment: Actually, the property name is AutoRenewing.